# get data from array in controller OpenCart

Tags: arrays, opencart

I have array in controller file:

```
$total_data = array();

                $totals = $this->model_sale_order->getOrderTotals($order_id);

                foreach ($totals as $total) {
                    $total_data[] = array(
                        'title' => $total['title'],
                        'text'  => $this->currency->format($total['value'], $order_info['currency_code'], $order_info['currency_value']),
                    );
                }
```

How pass `'text'` in this same controller file?
for example:`$text = $total['text'];`I getting an error `undefined index: text in....`
Where is a problem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you want to do, but you can send a variable from `controller` to `view` by `$data` in Opencart 2.x

You can send `$total_data` to `tpl` file this way:

```
$data['total_data'] = $total_data;
```

so your code must be:

```
$total_data = array();

$totals = $this->model_sale_order->getOrderTotals($order_id);

foreach ($totals as $total) {
    $total_data[] = array(
        'title' => $total['title'],
        'text'  => $this->currency->format($total['value'], $order_info['currency_code'], $order_info['currency_value'])
    );
}

$data['total_data'] = $total_data;
```

and use it in `view` (tpl file):

```
<?php 
    foreach($total_data as $total){
        echo $total['text']; 
    }
?>
```

Comment: Yes I know I can send to view. if you understand here are 'text' of total amount of the cart in numbers. So I need convert this amount to words before i send it to view. I need total amount in words.

Comment: the string: `$data['total_data'] = $total_data; ` seems  is not correct.